# VB Net - create a clipboard "management"

Tags: vb.net

Good morning.
One of our collaborators who contacts customers at fixed periods asks me to create a "management" (he calls it that) in which to insert, for each customer, the notes relating to that contact, indicating the date of the contact and writing what they are sayings.
I confess that I don't know where to start and, even if I don't ask for anything pre-established, I would need at least the basic indications: Should I use one (or more) DataBase? Do I (obviously) need to connect it with VB Net? How should I structure the DB? Text fields only? How and where to write notes? How to recall previously written notes? etc....
I have some experience in VB net, but I certainly don't know everything, so maybe the solution is at hand but I can't see it.
Hope someone can help me, thanks.

Comment: This is far too broad for SO, which is intended for questions on specific issues. You're basically asking how to design an application, which is to general.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Given that there are plenty of existing free note taking apps out there, e.g. [Microsoft Sticky Notes](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/microsoft-sticky-notes/9NBLGGH4QGHW?hl=en-us&gl=US) or [OneNote](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ww/microsoft-365/onenote/digital-note-taking-app) and the complexity and time  involved in creating your own from scratch, I don't think it's worth your effort/time.

Comment: Are you taking notes for specific customers?